# Cannot get "open in Client Application" to work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, quick-launch

I want to open documents directly from the Quick Launch menu. I have added the hyperlink but I get this error message each time:

> The file that you selected could not be found. Check the spelling of
>   the file name and verify that the location is correct. Make sure that
>   the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.

I click OK and it goes straight to the document but I would like to remove the error message.

I tried Library Settings > Advanced > Open in Client Browser. This did remove this error message:

> Close Excel  Error The workbook cannot be opened because it contains
>   the following features that are not supported by Excel in the browser:
>   • Data validation Would you like to try and open this file in Excel?

That is great but I still get the first error message when trying to open a document from a link on the Quick Launch menu (under Lists).

Can you help me get rid of that error message?
Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

At Quick launch navigation, you should make sure that the file URL has web parameter (`?Web=1`) like this

```
http://yoursite/DOC%20Word/Qassas.xlsx?Web=1
```

Also, it's preferred to get your file URL from document library as the following

[image]

Then copy it at your quick launch navigation URL .